# How to get base model score with ensemble from bagging

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I have created a `Bagging Ensemble Model`. The model is given below

```
def get_models():
    models = dict()
    n_trees = [10, 50, 100, 500, 500, 1000, 5000]
    for n in n_trees:
        models[str(n)] = BaggingRegressor(base_estimator=DecisionTreeRegressor(), n_estimators=n)
        return models
```

I want to get the score for each base model and the final ensemble model's score. So, I am using (with `base_estimator_`) the below code to access the base model

So, after fitting the main model I am using this code to get the score for base models

```
        for learner in regressor.base_estimator_:
            base_dfs.append(
                evaluate_base_learner(
                    learner, X_train[train_index], X_test, y_train[train_index], y_test, k, method, learner_name = type(model).__name__,
                )
            )
```

But I am getting an error
`TypeError: 'DecisionTreeRegressor' object is not iterable`. Could you tell me why I am getting this error and how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the `base` model, you should use the

```
for learner in regressor.estimators_:
```

More [info](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingRegressor.html)

Moroever, if you want to run more model as I understand based on your code you need to change the `return` code (not inside the `loop`)